# How to enable swapfiles in vim editor?

Tags: 20.04, files, swap, vim, vi

I have searched in google but i always found how to disable swapfiles. It said that we have to add

```
set noswapfile
```

in vim configuration file. And i tried to put `set swapfile` in the same configuration file. But still it did not work and no swapfile created.

Can anyone tell me how to enable it?

Comment: Try this: open a text file in vim: `vim textfile.txt` Enter `:set swapfile` Now swap file should appear! To have swap all the time add this line: `set swapfile` to ~/.vimrc

Comment: I already put that command in ~/.vimrc but it still did not work :(

Comment: Does it work when you are editing a text file?